# How to implement a fancy image rotator in Android?

Tags: android, image, slideshow

I have been trying to implement an image flipper like the image shown in this question..If anyone having any ideas or how to implement it can you help me with it.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Image Fliiper i am trying to implement]

Comment: http://androidworkz.com/2010/07/06/source-code-imageview-flipper-sd-card-scanner/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hear are the some of the example that you can taks as the base implementation...

[code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/)

[www.inter-fuser.com](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html)